# FindBy...In Spring JPA while using an enum error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to query a findBy...in in Spring JPA. It gives me an java.util.NoSuchElementException. Here's my code:

ProductType:

```
public enum ProductType {
   Product, Service, PeriodicalService;
}
```

Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<JsonStruct> findByProductsType(@RequestHeader("MarinaId") Integer idMarina, @PathVariable String[] productTypes){
    JsonStruct struct = new JsonStruct();
    struct.setStatusToSuccess();
    List<ProductType> productTypeList = Arrays.stream(productTypes).map(ProductType::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    struct.put("products", productService.findByProductTypeIn(productTypeList, idMarina));
    return new ResponseEntity<JsonStruct>(struct, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public List<Product> findByProductTypeIn(List<ProductType> productTypes, Integer marinaId){
    return productProvider.findByProductTypeIn(productTypes, marinaId);
}
```

Service:

```
List<Product> findByProductTypeIn(List<ProductType> productTypes, Integer marinaId);
```

Provider(this is the Repository):

```
List<Product> findByProductTypeIn(List<ProductType> productTypes, Integer marinaId);
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

As per [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference),if you are passing collection then it will support only 1 argument :

```
findByProductTypeIn(List<ProductType> productTypes);
```

If you want to use 2 arguments, you might need to iterate over `List<ProductType>` & then use something like this :

```
findByProductTypeAndMarinaid(ProductType p,Integer marinaid)
```

Provided your underlying db supports `ProductType` & `Integer` in query.

Answer (score 0):

You should have only 1 argument in your method.
The marinaId should be rénovée to match findByProductTypeIn method.